# Galaxy A03s Not Recording at 30 FPS Constant - Mouth Movement and Audio Out of Sync

Tags: video, audio, framerate, sync

I have an unlocked Samsung Galaxy A03s [1]. Per the Samsung website, it's supposed to be specked at FHD (1920 x 1080)@30fps. Unfortunately, I almost never get it to actually record at 30fps constant. Instead, it frequently records at what I think is about 17fps variable [2]. IIRC in extreme cases, the audio and video may even get out of sync.

I tried resetting the phone to factory defaults and turning on airplane mode several times, but I still get the lower 17fps.

Is there any way to get either the front or rear facing cameras on this phone to consistently do 30fps constant at 1920 x 1080? Presuming it's legal, would I be better off jail breaking this phone and installing a mobile GNU\Linux distro? Is it possible that buying a new external MicroSD card for the Samsung would alleviate these problems? Would coughing up $250 for a GoPro be the only way to truly resolve this?

Please keep amateurs on extremely limited budgets in mind when answering this question.

BTW: This somewhat tangential, but I also have a Kodak Z980. Unfortunately, it does worse with audio/video synchronization than my Samsung Android...

[1] - I believe I paid full retail price for said phone on the Samsung website and use the phone as much for video recording as I do for cellular service.
[2] - Sorry, I don't have the best memory. I also have problems with the phone automatically adjusting the lighting and focus when it shouldn't, but that's really a different question.